# Symfony security - get details on Access Denied

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

If i have a controller method protected with say
`is_granted('ROLE_XYZ')`, and the user does not have that role, how do I get hold of "ROLE_XYZ" in the exception? Currently, the exception message just has "Access Denied".

Or, in general, I want to know which expression failed.

Comment: I have not tried this myself but the AccessDenied exception is created in ControllerTrait::denyAccessUnlessGranted method.  You should be able to override the method and tweak the message.

Answer (score 1):

Hum I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.

But if you want to create a custom Access Denied Exception with a custom message, have a look at this page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html

Hope it helps

**EDIT**: In case the previous given link is broken, to create a custom message you have to:

- Create a class which implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface

```
class AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
    {
        public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
        {
            // ...

            return new Response($content, 403);
        }
    }
```

- Then modify your security.yaml to add your custom class

```
    # config/packages/security.yaml
    firewalls:
        # ...

        main:
            # ...
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
```

Comment: 1) If you not sure, do not post an answer. 2) Link-only answer become useless if the link changed or unreachable.

Comment: Ok sorry, I did not want to post an answer like this but I can't do a simple comment because I don't have enough reputation points... I'll take your advice. Thanks